# VS2012RC with Resharper hover?

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2012

I am using VS2012RC and I can't for the life of me figure out how to alter the color of the "hover element" that appears in Visual Studio "dark theme". The text below actually says `Declaration hides variable blah from outer scope`

[image: VS2012RC]

How can I change the color of this text so I can actually read it ? It's driving me insane and I'm hoping someone else is also experiencing this ?

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to resolve after much effort:

It's under `Data Tips` in the `Fonts and Colours` section. You have to change to a light color from the stupid setting of basically black.